# improving performance of a Python puzzle

Tags: python, performance

I was given the following puzzle to solve to obtain an interview, and not that I received notice yesterday that I was not selected (could not get the puzzle to perform that well), I was wondering if anyone out there may know how to help me solve this to perform better.  It was written in Python, and although I had 2 classes in Python a year or two ago, I'm still new to it compared to the world I used to work in (18 years of embedded C!)  Any help or advice so that I may learn from the experience appreciated. Puzzle problem submission for consideration of being selected for an interview there.

Puzzle Challenge Description Given:

> Consider a "word" as any sequence of capital letters A-Z (not limited to just "dictionary words"). For any word with at least two different letters, there are other words composed of the same letters but in a different order (for instance, STATIONARILY/ANTIROYALIST, which happen to both be dictionary words; for our purposes "AAIILNORSTTY" is also a "word" composed of the same letters as these two).  We can then assign a number to every word, based on where it falls in an alphabetically sorted list of all words made up of the same set of letters. One way to do this would be to generate the entire list of words and find the desired one, but this would be slow if the word is long.  Write a program which takes a word as a command line argument and prints to standard output its number. Do not use the method above of generating the entire list. Your program should be able to accept any word 20 letters or less in length (possibly with some letters repeated), and should use no more than 1 GB of memory and take no more than 500 milliseconds to run. Any answer we check will fit in a 64-bit integer.
>
> Sample words, with their rank:
>
> ```
> ABAB = 2
> AAAB = 1
> BAAA = 4
> QUESTION = 24572
> BOOKKEEPER = 10743
> NONINTUITIVENESS = 8222334634
> ```
>
> Your program will be judged on how fast it runs and how clearly the code is written. We
>   will be running your program as well as reading the source code, so anything you can do to make this process easier would be appreciated.

To Run this puzzle:  You can enter one word at the command line input (which is the current state it is in) or if you want to read the words you provided above in from a file, you can comment out  the `raw_input` to take in one word, and read in the `words.txt` file by uncommenting that code instead.

In the main part of program:

taking input word by word from command line - current state of code - will take your command line word inputs
`getInputFromCommandLine()`
--to run this way: command line: `python athenaPuzzleIterDeep.py`

uncomment the following if you want to take the input from `words.txt`, a file of words to read in instead
`words.txt` will be sent with the code
--to run this way: command line: `python athenaPuzzleIterDeep.py`
--but you also must have the `words.txt` file in the same directory as the python program
`wordList = loadWords()`

`wordNumberOrdering(wordList)`

Performance enhancements investigated that did not end up being good enough: iterative deepening:
Iterative deepening was tried to get the DFS (depth-first-search) space advantage with BFS's (breadth-first-search) time and shallow solution advantage.  So can try running DFS with depth limits: try depth of tree = 1, then 2, 3,...etc.  So rather than building entire graph, at each tree level, call DFS to see if solution found.  DFS will search going down left side of tree's child nodes first, but will eventually search every node, so takes too much time while not taking much space.  However, if you use the level limitation idea from BFS, only building the tree level by level and then searching it with DFS,that is the idea of iterative deepening.

Iterative Deepening did NOT provide the needed performance improvements.  I also tried to include the priority queue python import, but could not get it to install correctly on my linux version.

Words.txt file contained:

```
ABAB
AAAB
BAAA
QUESTION
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BOOKKEEPER
BOOKKEEPERS
STATIONARILY
NONINTUITIVENESS
```

Here’s the code:

```
import random
import string
from math import factorial
import itertools
from functools import update_wrapper
import time
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
# works for functions with hashable (immuatble) arguments
# Example usage: permutations = memoize(itertools.permutations)

ALPHABET_LETTERS = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

globalMemCache = {}
def memoize(f):
# define "wrapper" function that checks cache for
# previously computed answer, only calling f if this
# is a new problem.
    def memf(*x):
        permutationsInCache = []
        if x not in memf.cache:
            memf.cache[x] = f(*x)
        return memf.cache[x]

     # initialize wrapper function's cache.  store cache as
     # attribute of function so we can look at its value.
     memf.cache = globalMemCache
     return memf

def isValidWord(word):
    lenWord = len(word)
    if (lenWord > 20):
        print "word > 20 letters is NOT acceptable as input"
        print " "
        return False
    elif (lenWord >= 11):
        print "word >= 11 letters is NOT acceptable as input for this current iterative deepening solution"
        print "my iterative deepening solution takes too much time and space for words >= 11 letters"
        print " "
        return False

    wordInAlphabet = True
    for letter in word:
        if (wordInAlphabet != True) or (letter not in ALPHABET_LETTERS):
            wordInAlphabet = False

    return wordInAlphabet

permutationsMemoized = memoize(itertools.permutations)

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def loadWords():
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    wordList = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordList.append(line.strip().lower())
    print "  ", len(wordList), "words loaded."
    return wordList

def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))

def printPath(path):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(path)):
        if i == len(path) - 1:
            result = result + str(path[i])
        else:
            result = result + str(path[i]) + '->'
    return result

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, index):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.index = index
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getIndex(self):
        return self.index
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, src, dest):
        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest
    def getSource(self):
        return self.src
    def getDestination(self):
        return self.dest
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.src) + '->' + str(self.dest)

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.list.insert(0,item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.list.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.list) == 0

def DFSShortest(graph, start, end, path = [], shortest = None, index = 1000):
    newGraph = graph
    path = path + [start]
    if str(start) == str(end):
        index = start.index
        newPath = path
        return newPath,index
    else:
        anyChildren = graph.childrenOf(start)
        if (anyChildren != None) and (index == 1000):
            for node in graph.childrenOf(start):
                if node not in path: #avoid cycles
                    if (shortest == None) or  ( (shortest != None) and (len(path) < len(shortest))) :
                        newPath,index = DFSShortest(newGraph,node,end,path)
                        if newPath != None:
                            shortest = newPath
                        if (index != 1000):
                            return shortest,index

        elif (anyChildren == None) and (index == 1000):
            newPath,index = DFSShortest(newGraph,graph.parents[start],end,path)
            if newPath != None:
                shortest = newPath
            if (index != 1000):
                return shortest,index

    return shortest,index

def BFS(graph, start, end, q):
    initPath = [start]
    q.append(initPath)
    while len(q) != 0:
        tmpPath = q.pop(0)
        lastNode = tmpPath[len(tmpPath) - 1]
        if str(lastNode) == str(end):
            return lastNode.index
        if (graph.childrenOf(lastNode) != []):
            printPath(graph.childrenOf(lastNode))
            for linkNode in graph.childrenOf(lastNode):
                if linkNode not in tmpPath:
                    newPath = tmpPath + [linkNode]
                    q.append(newPath)
    return None

class Digraph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = set([])
        self.edges = {}
        self.parents = {}
    def addNode(self, node):
        if node in self.nodes:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate node')
        else:
            self.nodes.add(node)
            self.edges[node] = []
            #print "added edges = [] for node " + str(node)
    def addEdge(self, edge):
        src = edge.getSource()
        dest = edge.getDestination()
        self.edges[src].append(dest)
        self.parents[dest] = src
    def childrenOf(self, node):
        if (self.edges[node]):
            return self.edges[node]   
        else:
            return None 
    def hasNode(self, node):
        return node in self.nodes
    def __str__(self):
        res = ''
        for k in self.edges:
            for d in self.edges[k]:
                res = res + str(k) + '->' + str(d) + '\n'
        return res[:-1]

class Graph(Digraph):
    def addEdge(self, edge):
        Digraph.addEdge(self, edge)

def addEdgesForTreesWith4Nodes(g,childNode,factorNum,i,lenList,wordNodes):
    if (i + factorNum + 1) < lenList:
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[childNode + 1],wordNodes[i + factorNum + 1]))
    if (i + factorNum + 2) < lenList:
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[childNode + 1],wordNodes[i + factorNum + 2]))

def addEdgesForTreesWithMoreThan4Nodes(g,childNode,factorNum,i,lenList,wordNodes, numChildrenNodesThisLevel, numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel):
    if (i + factorNum + numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel) < lenList:
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[childNode + i],wordNodes[i + factorNum + numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel]))
    if (i + factorNum + numChildrenNodesThisLevel + 1) < lenList:
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[childNode + i],wordNodes[i + factorNum + numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel + 1]))

"""
Can try using iterative deepening to get the DFS space advantage with BFS's time and shallow
solution advantage.  So can try running DFS with depth limits: try depth of tree = 1, then 2, 3,...etc
"""
"""
Also - you can avoid the log(n) overhead in DFS/BFS with a priority queue (had trouble downloaded and installing on my computer!)
"""
def iterativeDeepeningSolution(wordNodes, saveWord, saveWordTuple, lenList):
#rather than building entire graph, at each tree level, call DFS to see if solution found
#DFS will search going down left side of tree's child nodes first, but will eventually search
#every node, so takes too much time while not taking much space.  However, if you use the level
#limitation idea from BFS, only building the tree level by level and then searching it with DFS,
#that is the idea of iterative deepening.
    index = 0
    q = []
    shortest = None
    saveNodes = wordNodes

    i = 0
    totalNodes = 1
    numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel = 0

    while i < lenList:
        index = 0
        if (i > 0):
            numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel = numChildrenNodesThisLevel

        numChildrenNodesThisLevel = 2**i #number of children nodes at level

        if (i > 0):
            totalNodes += numChildrenNodesThisLevel

        if (numChildrenNodesThisLevel > 1) and (numChildrenNodesThisLevel <= 32): #only search 32 children nodes or less (level 5 of tree, 2**5 = 32):
            #print "build graph - if previous level already searched - just add this level of children nodes"
            if (numChildrenNodesThisLevel == 2): #new graph since none built when it was just a root node
                g = Graph()
                for n in range(numChildrenNodesThisLevel + 1):
                    g.addNode(wordNodes[n])
            else: #use graph from last level of children added - don't rebuild graph
                n = numChildrenNodesThisLevel - 1
                while (n < lenList) and (n < (totalNodes)):
                    g.addNode(wordNodes[n])
                    n += 1

        elif (numChildrenNodesThisLevel > 32): #only search 32 children nodes or less (level 5 of tree, 2**5 = 32)
            print "word graph just searched: " + str(saveWord)
            print "cannot go further searching in iterative deepening - tree will take too much space and time to search"
            print "Tree Level = " + str(i) + " num children at this level " + str(numChildrenNodesThisLevel) + " total nodes in graph " + str(totalNodes)
            print "Last Level Searched " + str(i - 1) + " num children at this level " + str(numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel) + " total nodes in graph " + str(totalNodes - numChildrenNodesThisLevel)
            print " "
            return

        if (numChildrenNodesThisLevel > 2):
            childNode = 0
            while childNode < numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel:
                if (childNode > 0):
                    factorNum = childNode * 2
                else:
                    factorNum = childNode
                if (numChildrenNodesThisLevel == 4):
                    addEdgesForTreesWith4Nodes(g,childNode,factorNum,i,lenList,wordNodes)
                elif (numChildrenNodesThisLevel > 4):                  addEdgesForTreesWithMoreThan4Nodes(g,childNode,factorNum,i,lenList,wordNodes,numChildrenNodesThisLevel,numChildrenNodesPreviousLevel)
                childNode += 1
            startNode = wordNodes[0]
            endNode = Node(str(saveWordTuple),0)
            index = 1000
            path,index = DFSShortest(g, startNode, endNode, q, shortest, index)
            if (index != 1000): #made up error - not searching 1000 nodes or more at this time - soln found
                print saveWord + " = " + str(index + 1)
                print " "
                return
            i += 1
            wordNodes = saveNodes

        elif (numChildrenNodesThisLevel == 2): #so new graph just formed of 3 nodes (including root) - no edges on it yet
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[0],wordNodes[1]))
        g.addEdge(Edge(wordNodes[0],wordNodes[2]))

        startNode = wordNodes[0]
        endNode = Node(str(saveWordTuple),0)
        index = 1000
        path,index = DFSShortest(g, startNode, endNode, q, shortest, index)
        if (index != 1000): #made up error - not searching 1000 nodes or more at this time - soln found
            print saveWord + " = " + str(index + 1)
            print " "
            return
        i += 1
        wordNodes = saveNodes
    elif (numChildrenNodesThisLevel == 1):
        startNode = wordNodes[0]
        oneNode = Node(str(saveWordTuple),0)
        if str(oneNode) == str(startNode):
            print saveWord + " = " + str(startNode.index + 1)
            print " "
            return
        else:
            i += 1
            wordNodes = saveNodes

def wordNumberOrdering(wordList):

    for word in wordList:
        permutationTuples = []
        withDupsList = []
        noDupsList = []
        noDupsStringList = []
        index = 0
        outputDict = {}
        saveWord = ""
        saveWordTuple = []

        wordLen = len(word)
        if (wordLen <= 10):
            saveWord = word
            saveWordTuple = tuple(saveWord,)
            permutationTuples = permutationsMemoized(word)
            for tupleStr in permutationTuples:
                withDupsList.append(tupleStr)
            noDupsList = remove_duplicates(withDupsList)
            lenList = len(noDupsList) 

            noDupsList.sort()
            wordNodes = []
            i = 0
            for name in noDupsList:
                wordNodes.append(Node(str(name),i))
                i += 1 #index of list to print when found for this puzzle
            iterativeDeepeningSolution(wordNodes, saveWord, saveWordTuple, lenList)

        elif (wordLen > 20):
            print word
            print "word length too long (> 20 chars): " + str(wordLen) 
            print " "
        elif (wordLen >= 11):
            print word
            print "word length too long for this current solution to puzzle (>= 11 chars): " + str(wordLen) 
            print " "

def oneWordInputFromCommandLineAtATime(word):
    permutationTuples = []
    withDupsList = []
    noDupsList = []
    noDupsStringList = []
    index = 0
    outputDict = {}
    saveWord = ""
    saveWordTuple = []

    saveWord = word
    saveWordTuple = tuple(saveWord,)
    permutationTuples = permutationsMemoized(word)

    for tupleStr in permutationTuples:
        withDupsList.append(tupleStr)
    noDupsList = remove_duplicates(withDupsList)
    lenList = len(noDupsList) 

    noDupsList.sort()
    wordNodes = []
    i = 0
    for name in noDupsList:
        wordNodes.append(Node(str(name),i))
        i += 1 #index of list to print when found for this puzzle
    iterativeDeepeningSolution(wordNodes, saveWord, saveWordTuple, lenList)

def getInputFromCommandLine():
    guessWord = ""
    guessWordLowCase = ""
    validWord = False

    takeInput = True
    while (takeInput == True):
        guessWord = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ').decode('utf-8')
        guessWordLowCase = guessWord.lower()
        print "word being considered " + guessWordLowCase
        if (guessWordLowCase == "."):
            takeInput = False
        else: #otherwise consider this word as an input from command line
            validWord = isValidWord(guessWordLowCase)
            if (validWord == False):
                guessWordLowCase + " is INVALID"
                print "Invalid word, please try again"
                print "                                                "
            else:
                oneWordInputFromCommandLineAtATime(guessWordLowCase)
    print "Goodbye!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
#taking input word by word from command line
    getInputFromCommandLine()
#uncomment the following if you want to take the input from words.txt, a file of words to read in instead
    #wordList = loadWords()

    #wordNumberOrdering(wordList)
```

Comment: And exceptionally much better received if you don't post a code block with a horizontal scroll bar from hell. The part of the question which is just pure text, try to format it as pure text, and not as code.

Comment: make your methods smaller, each method should do one thing only, and do it well!

Comment: This code is so bad it makes me where your "18 years of embedded C" experience went. It's certainly not demonstrated here.

Comment: @Lasse: Sorry, that was partly my doing. The original code was in a GitHub Gist, and I moved it into the question. I noticed that there was some prose in a docstring, but I thought it was just documentation. I’ve moved it out after doing a little extra formatting.

Comment: the if-else conditions of `isValidWord(word):`  does not make any sense, and so many objects are created in the `for loop` in method `wordNumberOrdering(wordList):`

Comment: The problem description does not mention anything about a known list of words against which to rank new words. Are we to assume such a word list *does* exist, or *not* ? If not, I would assume that the correct way to determine some kind of rank value would be to just assume an "infinite" number of words available, using all the possible symbols, and then assigning a fixed rank value to a word solely depending on its characters, having no knowledge about any other words in the dictionary.

Comment: Apologies - I've only asked a few questions on stack overflow in the past, and perhaps this was the wrong place for asking questions on a language such as Python where I have 2 introductory level classes in the area.  I do know C better, and I do know Python as well now, but I don't know how to make the performance work better here, and from the responses received, I see that this forum is not the place to have asked, and I will go to a more appropriate place for help in the future, if I am correct in assuming this was an inappropriate place to ask this.  Sorry.  Happy 4rth of July.

Comment: The only word list was provided as shown - the numbers were from the permutations, since small cases worked, and the number output were the expected answer.  I forgot to mention that, and thank you to those that responded.

Comment: The company that sent it to me provided those input cases and expected answers.  It's not urgent for me to know how to make the larger cases perform better, so perhaps I'll return to it someday.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key here is thinking in terms of ranking distinct permutations.  Given BAAA, for example, we know that the index is >= that of all the A*** ones, so if we can compute how many there are we don't need to go through them explicitly.  How many are there?  Well, that's simply how many distinct permutations A*** there are.  That's easy to compute, but then we have to figure out where in all the B*** we fall-- and that reduces to figuring out where AAA is relative to the first B*** (which we know is the number of A***s).

Something like this should work, which simply generalizes that idea. (Disclaimer: this is untested-- could easily be edge cases I'm forgetting, etc., but I'm pretty confident the basic idea is sound).

```
from math import factorial
from collections import Counter

def number_of_distinct_permutations(counts):
    f = factorial(sum(counts.values()))
    for letter, count in counts.items():
        f //= factorial(count)
    return f

def compute_index(word, index=0):
    if not word:
        return index + 1
    pending = Counter(word)
    head = word[0]
    for p in sorted(pending):
        if p < head:
            index += number_of_distinct_permutations(pending - Counter(p))
        if p == head:
            index += compute_index(word[1:])
    return index


test_data = {"ABAB": 2,
             "AAAB": 1,
             "BAAA": 4,
             "QUESTION": 24572,
             "BOOKKEEPER": 10743,
             "NONINTUITIVENESS": 8222334634}

print("word, reference, calculated")
for k,v in sorted(test_data.items()):
    print (k, v, compute_index(k))
```

which produces

```
word, reference, calculated
AAAB 1 1
ABAB 2 2
BAAA 4 4
BOOKKEEPER 10743 10743
NONINTUITIVENESS 8222334634 8222334634
QUESTION 24572 24572
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-reursive variation over [DSM's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580815/improving-performance-of-a-python-puzzle/24582351#24582351) (the general idea is entirely his/hers):

```
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial

def number_of_distinct_permutations(counted):
    result = factorial(sum(counted))
    for each in counted:
        result //= factorial(each)
    return result

def anagram_number(iterable):
    elems = list(iterable)
    tally = Counter()
    index = 1
    while elems:
        current = elems.pop()
        tally[current] += 1
        for item in tally:
            if item < current:
                tally[item] -= 1
                index += number_of_distinct_permutations(tally.values())
                tally[item] += 1
    return index
```

Answer (score 0):

I heard about this question yesterday, independently of this forum.  Below is a straightforward solution in C.   It has some Win32 stuff mixed in but should be easily converted to python (or whatever).  It simply relies of the fact that the number of words of letters with multiplicities m1 ... mk is given by the multinomial coefficient (SUM(mi))!/PRODUCT(mi!).  It uses lower case (a-z) and is in rough form, with absolutely no error control.  Here it (multinom.exe) is in action along with multinom2.exe which answers the reverse question ... given the letters and the index, find the string.  Below is the code

multinom.exe question
index = 24572

multinom2.exe noitseuq 24572
string = question

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ULONGLONG fact( ULONGLONG n )
{
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 1;
    return n * fact(n-1);
}

ULONGLONG multinom( INT mults[] ) // = (SUM(M))! / PROD(M!)
{
    ULONGLONG n = 0;
    for ( INT i=0; i<26; i++ )
        n += mults[i];
    ULONGLONG result = fact(n);
    for ( INT i=0; i<26; i++ )
        if ( mults[i] )
            result /= fact(mults[i]);
    return result;
}

// uses a~z as alphabet; strings up to 20 chars; no safeguards or E/C whatsoever.
INT main ( INT argc, LPSTR* argv )
{
    ULONGLONG index = 1; // we'll add to this any earlier strings

    CHAR str[21];
    lstrcpy(str, argv[1]);

    INT mults[26] = {0}; // initialize multiplicities to zero

    for ( CHAR *p=str; *p != 0; p++ ) // set multiplicities that are non-zero
    {
        mults[*p - 'a'] += 1;   
    }

    for ( CHAR *p = str; *p != 0; p++ ) // iterate through the characters of str
    {
        for ( INT i=0; i < (*p - 'a'); i++ ) // check each character lexicographically before *p
        {
            if ( mults[i] ) // it's in the string; count (as earlier in the list) the strings that start with it
            {
                mults[i] -= 1;
                index += multinom(mults);
                mults[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        // At this point we've counted all the words that start with an earlier character.
        // Any remaining earlier words must match up to this point.  So ...
        mults[*p - 'a'] -= 1; // p will be incremented so, in effect, forget this character and move on
    }
    printf("index = %I64u\n", index);
    return 0;
}
```